# Suppose that $F$ is analytic in a convex domain $G$ and $Re(F')>0$. Prove or disprove: $F$ is univalent in $G$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $F$ is analytic in a convex domain $G$ and $Re(F')>0$. Prove or disprove: $F$ is univalent in $G$

My professor gave this example in class and gave us the solution hand out without any explanation. So I wonder if anyone would please help me understand his proof.

Here is his proof, I break it into steps so that I can tell which step I don't understand.

1. Assume that $z_1 \not =z_2$ and $F(z_1)=F(z_2)$
2. Define $\beta(t)=z_1+t(z_2-z_1)$, $\gamma(t)=F'[\beta(t)]$ with $0<t<1$
3. $\int_\beta F'(z)dz=0$
4. $\int_\beta F'(z)dz=\int_0^1F'(z_1+t(z_2-z_1))(z_2-z_1)dt=0$
5. $\int_0^1F'(z_1+t(z_2-z_1))dt=\lim \sum_k F'(z_1 +t_k(z_2-z_1)) \Delta t_k$
6. The last sum represent the convex combination of point on $\{\gamma\}$ so zero belong to the closed convex hull of $\{\gamma\}$

Step 1: I understand he wanted to prove by contradiction

Step 2: I guess he want to define a parametrize, but why $\beta$ has to be that equation? Does he implies that $\beta$ is a closed curve?, and then where the $\gamma$ come from?

Step 3: I guess that happen because $\beta$ is a closed curve

Step 4: I guess he just throw in the $\gamma$ and do the line integral

Step 5: I have no idea what he's trying to do here

Step 6: I have no clue. So what is the contradiction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z_1, z_2\in G$ with $z_1 \neq z_2$, then

$$\operatorname{Re}\frac{F(z_2) - F(z_1)}{z_2 - z_1} = \operatorname{Re}\int_{[z_1,z_2]} \frac{F'(z)}{z_2 - z_1}\, dz = \int_0^1 \operatorname{Re}F'((1 - t)z_1 + tz_2)\, dt > 0,$$

and therefore $F(z_1) \neq F(z_2)$.

Comment: are you using the mean value theorem?

Comment: No, I used $F(z_2) - F(z_1) = \int_{[z_1,z_2]} F'(z)\, dz$, where $[z_1,z_2]$ is the straight line segment from $z_1$ to $z_2$.

Comment: oh, I think I understand your answer, the only question I have is about $\beta$ and $\gamma$, we just force them to be like that ? I mean, how do I know $t\in (0,1)$? why can't $t <0$ or bigger than $1$?

Comment: yes, I understand that, I just don't understand why he declare $\gamma =F'(\beta)$ with $0<t<1$

Comment: He didn't have to. It's enough to say $\int_{\beta} F'(z)\, dz = \int_0^1 F'(\beta(t))\beta'(t)\, dt$.

Comment: I guess I didn't ask clear enough. My question is why $\int _\beta =\int_0^1$. In other word, how do I know $t$ is in that interval?

Comment: That's because it was defined that way.